# What Is The Cheapest VM That Can Be Used As An AKS Node?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform

I am testing out some Terraform code to create a Kubernetes cluster so I chose the smallest/cheapest VM

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "k8s" {
    name                = "${var.cluster_name}"
    location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location}"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name}"
    dns_prefix          = "${var.dns_prefix}"

    agent_pool_profile {
        name            = "agentpool"
        count           = "${var.agent_count}"
        vm_size         = "Standard_B1s"
        os_type         = "Linux"
        os_disk_size_gb = "${var.agent_disk_size}"
    }

    service_principal {
        client_id     = "${var.client_id}"
        client_secret = "${var.client_secret}"
    }
}
```

However, when I `terraform apply` I get this error message back from azure:

> "The VM SKU chosen for this cluster `Standard_B1s` does not have enough CPU/memory to run as an AKS node."

How do I list the valid VM SKUs for AKS nodes and sort them by cost?

Comment: I marked it as useful. I'll leave it open for another 24 hours before accepting in case there is a command line way of listing valid VMs.

Comment: Kubernetes minimal requirements could be found here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/#before-you-begin   Other recommendations should take into account workload analysis.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to select an instance with **at least 3.5 GB of memory**. Read *A note on node size* from this [blog](https://stackify.com/azure-container-service-kubernetes/). You can list the VM size and price on the [Azure sales site](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/pricing/details/virtual-machines/linux/).

Currently, the cheapest is `Standard_B2s` with 4 GB RAM. You can also sort it directly in the Azure portal.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

You do a B1 which is cheaper than B2 if you resize the vmss, then upgrade the instance.
This one is $3.80/month for Linux and $10.22/month for Windows

For whatever reason you can't do this in Terraform yet.

Step 1:
Click on vmss -> settings -> size -> see all sizes (in small print) -> resize

Step 2:
Click on vmss -> settings -> instance -> _0 -> upgrade (at top controller bar)

I wouldn't worry about the vm instance size too much. This is where Terraform rips you off. os_disk_size_gb. Set this lower otherwise it defaults to $20/month per instance. There seems to be no way to change the tier, they defaulted to a premium 128GB disk, and made it seem like you would only spend $30 per node.

UPDATE:
I started experiencing some problems with instance at size b1ls.

Comment: That's interesting. However, if you can't do it automatically it doesn't really help me.

Comment: What I did is upped with Terraform, then wrote a PowerShell script to do the resize. You can then write a PowerShell that init and apply Terraform then runs the other PowerShell, so it is fully automated. However, I am running into a problem where I can't delete namespace with kubectl with the b1ls. I'll update my answer soon if resizing to b1ls does not make sense. I'd focus on the os_disk_size_gb if you are trying to save money. You can then write a script to deallocate vmss when not in use or terraform destroy when not in use.

Comment: I noticed an additional 20 euros of cost when I launched an AKS cluster and it turned out to be the managed Premium SSD disk with no way of changing it. The metrics show that Azure actually needs about 90GB of the 128GB for who knows what. Because you need all this side business you still end up paying an aweful lot for a development cluster :(

Comment: If you're just setting up a test environment you can use Terraform and destroy it and recreate it every time your using it/ done using it. That is what I did. It only cost me pennies if I remember right. Would probably need some Azure Pipelines too

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to existing answer. I dont think there is an enum to list all the valid sizes of vms, but if you look at the [API definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/managedclusters/createorupdate#containerservicevmsizetypes), it lists all of them pretty clearly.

And you can use azureprice.net or something similar to figure out cheapest vm for your region (usually its B series).